# Does 7z have options for efficiently extracting large numbers of files?

Tags: 7zip

Using 7z to unzip a 50 GB file that contains about 600,000 files, the speed of extraction dramatically drops as the number of extracted files increases. It takes approximately 20 hours to unzip the entire batch.

I wrote a Linux script that runs in parallel to the 7z process. It moves unzipped files to another directory so that the 7z target directory never accumulates too many files. Doing this dropped the total time to about 30 minutes.

While this works, is there a better way to do this? Preferably built into 7z?

Running on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

7-Zip [64] V16.02

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having the same issue...

Comment: No. Still using the workaround.